# Links not working in firefox or safari, but working fine in opera, chrome, ie

Tags: css

The links on a site I'm working with are working in opera, chrome, and ie, but not in firefox or safari. www.dovetailrecords.com (click on "artists"). I've searched the forum and some other forums and tried some of the suggestions, but none seem to be working. It seems clear that I've got a css problem and some sort of problem with overlapping, but for the life of me, I can't figure it out.

I'm relatively new to this game, so I'm sure in the end the problem will be a simple one that I probably should have seen. In any case, any help is really really appreciated!!

Thanks,

Jack

Comment: Why would you use an image as menu? This is bad practise!

Comment: They work fine for me. On the latest Firefox version.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the `<a>` tags are not closed properly and  not wrapping the `<img>` tags.

```
<a href="sads/bioback.html" target="back"</a><img src="sads/thesadslogo2.jpg" width="315" height="115" class="artimg2">
```

Close the `<a` and move the `</a>` to after the `<img>`. Like this:

```
<a href="sads/bioback.html" target="back"><img src="sads/thesadslogo2.jpg" width="315" height="115" class="artimg2"></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't make a lot of sense. Safari and Chrome use the same engine but you say this only works in Chrome so this is starting out weird. You aren't using a doctype and are in quirks mode. Add this to your very first line and see where we stand:

`<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN"
   "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">`

Also validate your html and css for those lists of errors.